# WCF Rest Session Aunthentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, wcf, rest

I am new to WCF rest service creation. So please bear with me.

I have created a html5 AngularJS application, which is hosted in node.

Then i have created a WCF rest application.

My Client (html5 app) connects with the wcf application to get/set data, which is JSON.

Upto this everything is working fine.

Now i need to do User credentials validation, session management is wcf.

I am not sure which is the best way to do it.

Please help.

Thanks,
Karthikeyan J

Comment: Do you host your WCF-service in IIS ? Which binding do you use ? BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding or WebHttpBinding ?